# Facebook login sdk is blocked by Microsoft Edge tracking prevention

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, microsoft-edge

I'm using facebook login javascript sdk for social login functionality and it is blocked on Microsoft Edge browser, is there any way to make it work?

I tried to load the script using proxy but it's still blocked.
I also noticed some browsers like firefox and chrome also blocked facebook sdk before, but still, I'm wondering if there is any way to bypass this rather than waiting for an update from Microsoft to fix this or manually add the sdk as an exception to the Tracking prevention.

Any help is very appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: You say Firefox and Chrome also blocked Facebook sdk before, do they block it at present? Do you mean Facebook sdk won't be blocked if you turn off Tracking prevention in Edge? If it is blocked, does it have any error message in console or on the page?

Comment: If there were ways to bypass this, then not only you would be using them, but also everyone else.

Comment: @YuZhou I haven't tried it on google chrome but yes firefox is not blocking it. And also yes, if the tracking prevention feature on Edge is off then it is working. Also yes, there is an error message saying it is being blocked by the client (Edge).

Comment: @CBroe well, that's why I said "I'm wondering", who knows there is someone that know how to that. Not sure what's the point of your comment.

Comment: The point is, that it would be a flaw in the implementation of this tracker-blocking feature, if any tracking provider, or website creator that _uses_ a script that is classified as tracker, was able to circumvent it.